# Does native methods in Java, operating system specific?

Tags: java, string, operating-system, native

**Problem Description** : - During one discussion I found that programmer stuck at point and I thought I should put on forum.

Today I was searching array conversion into char array. And I checked definition of **toCharArray()** method of string class.

```
char str[] = "native".toCharArray();
```

**toCharArray() definition : -**

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    char result[] = new char[count];
    getChars(0, count, result, 0);
    return result;
}
```

**getChars definition: -**

```
public void getChars(int srcBegin,int srcEnd,char dst[],int dstBegin){
   if(srcBegin<0){
       throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcBegin);
   }
   if(srcEnd>count){
       throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd);
   }
   if(srcBegin>srcEnd){
       throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(srcEnd-srcBegin);
   }
   System.arraycopy(value,offset+srcBegin,dst,dstBegin,srcEnd-srcBegin);
}
```

**Then a native method: -**

```
public static native void arraycopy(Object src,  int  srcPos,
                                        Object dest, int destPos,
                                         int length);
```

**Here I don't have to understand native but I have to know In such a native method define here in a same way different native method will define for other operating system.**

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's native is because this otherwise expensive function can be heavily optimized by using native code.

But the behavior is the same whatever the OS.

Comment: @shivquery You see, back when Java did not have JIT (just in time) optimization and the HotSpot JVM, every line of bytecode needed to be interpreted and then executed. (programs can still be run this way if you like). Therefore, since Java ran much slower than native code, and since `System.arraycopy` was a large method, they decided to make it `native`. Now, Java programs have near-native speeds, so there is no need to make it as native. However, to make the method definition the same, they left it as `native`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Java language's main benefit is the *portability* across hardware platforms and operating systems.  So a particular method, although is declared as native, should not change your *signature*, for example, the name or the arguments, in order to follow this principle.

However, what can change is the *implementation* of native method. This implementation is *platform-specific*. The JNI provides a way to use any native methods in a *platform-independent way*.

Answer (score 2):

Most operations are OS independent, where ever possible.

There are some obvious exceptions e.g. Runtime.exec(String command) will be entirely dependant  on which commands you have installed.

This will only create filenames allowed by the OS.  On Linux you can use characters which are invalid in Windows.  Also Windows is case insensitive which means if you have another file which would have the same name, ignoring case, it will overwrite on Windows, but create a new file in Linux.

```
new FileOutputStream(String filename)
```

A common gotcha is that Linux allows you to delete files which have not been closed, but windows will not.  This can lead to different behaviour on different platforms.